# Accessing Files from iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I know it is possible to access the gallery photos and pick them as UIImage using UIImagePickerController, but I want to know whether all other files like doc, txt, pdf etc can be accessed from device please help.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no GUI API to access the file system, you can create your own UI and read and write from your app's documents folder though.

Comment: My question may be silly anyhow I want to know the answer, are filesystem in which we(developers) are storing documents and the iPhone's saved documents are different? if so, then NSFileManager will give access to iPhone's documents or file system?

Comment: @user2634244 Since the iOS applications are sandboxed for security reasons, there restrictions on what parts of the file system an app can access. An app's documents folder is part of the file system you can access via `NSFileManager`.

Comment: thanks, so i have some pdf files stored in the iphone, is it possible to get it?

Comment: @user2634244 That depends on where you put them. You need to be specific about these things :)

Comment: you mean to say that I can get the files which I have uploaded through my app only?

Answer (score 3):

You can, but there's no built-in picker like there is for images. Take a look at the [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class for enumerating directories and working with files.

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal space to store that document in iphone like photos and videos. but you can store in your app and and using itunes file sharing you can access it.
here is the way to enable itunes file sharing.
you can store in **icloud** and access it from app.

> 1. Select your project in top left
> 2. Select target in next column
> 3. Click on Info tab
> 4. In Custom iOS Target Properties, hover mouse over any row and click +
> 5. In popup, select "**Application supports iTunes file sharing**", then set Value to YES on right
> 6. Click Validate Settings at bottom to make sure all is good